# TYPO3 8.7.32: html is output as text in setup

Tags: html, cookies, typo3, typo3-8.x

Hello I use the mindshap cookie hint extention which is also displayed in the frontend. everything except the link is also output correctly. Does anyone know how I can add a link to hint.message or what I did wrong.

```
plugin.tx_mindshapecookiehint {

  _LOCAL_LANG.de {
        hint.learnMore = Weitere Informationen.
        hint.dismiss = OK
        hint.message = Diese Webseite verwendet Cookies. Wenn Sie weiter auf dieser Seite bleiben, stimmen Sie den <a class="cookie-link" href="foo">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> zu.
  }
}
```

**Solution:**
I added in the Cookie file this:

```
 message: '<f:format.raw><f:translate key="hint.message" /></f:format.raw>'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hit the Local Language lables are just plaintext. the encoding usually happens at the output. most likly fluid templating is used for the output. which html-encodeds by default to avoid security problems.

you might use the fluid view helper <f:format.raw> to avoid escaping in your template. (but your langauge string must have the properencoding

and never put user input into format.raw as this is almost certainly a security issue

Comment: thank you :) I added form.raw to my cookie.html